# Conditional formatting using openxlsx package in R not working

Tags: r, conditional-formatting, openxlsx

I have the following code, where I want the column `Score` to be conditionally formatted based on the value of the column `max`. If the score is 8 and max is 8, green. If the score is 4 and max is 8, yellow. if the score is 4 and max is 4 then green. If the score is 2 and max is 4 then yellow. If the score is 0 then red. However, the below does not seem to work (only testing for green).

**EDITED code based on G5W suggestion**

so with the code below I do not get the conditional formatting, but I also get the error message: [image] followed by [image]

Clicking on the link to the logfile provides me with the following xml output [image]

```r
library(tibble)
library(openxlsx)

data <- tribble(
  ~Week, ~Facility, ~Indicator, ~`Indicator Value`, ~`Yellow Gap`, ~`Green Gap`, ~Score, ~max,
  8, "Mngeta Health Center", "3MMD Coverage", 0.96, -13, 10, 4, 8,
  8, "Mngeta Health Center", "12 Month Retention", 0.96, 35, 50, 2, 4,
  8, "Mngeta Health Center", "Appointment Adherence", 0.97, 11, 24, 0, 8,
  8, "Mngeta Health Center", "EID 12 Months", 1, 0, 0, 8, 8,
  8, "Mngeta Health Center", "Early Retention", 1, 0, 0, 8, 8,
  8, "Mngeta Health Center", "Recent Retention", 1.04, -19, -5, 8, 8,
  8, "Mngeta Health Center", "6MMD Coverage", 0.98, -29, -9, 8, 8,
  8, "Mngeta Health Center", "IPT Coverage", 0.99, -15, -1, 4, 4,
  8, "Mngeta Health Center", "EID 2 Months", 1, 0, 0, 8, 8,
  8, "Mngeta Health Center", "Viral Load Coverage", 0.95, -67, -2, 8, 8
)

# Convert Score column to numeric
data$Score <- as.numeric(data$Score)

wb <- createWorkbook()

# Add a new worksheet
addWorksheet(wb, "Formatted Data")

# Write the data to the worksheet
writeData(wb, "Formatted Data", data)

# Create a style object for green color
green_style <- createStyle(bgFill = "green")

conditionalFormatting(wb, sheet = "Formatted Data",
                      cols = which(colnames(data) == "Score"), rows = 1:(nrow(data)+1),
                      rule = '"Score"==8 & "max"==8', style = green_style)

saveWorkbook(wb, "formatted_data.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Two problems. First, if you want to use the column name, it must be quoted for Excel. Second,  because you have a header row, the rows that you want to test go up to nrow(data)+1.   Try:

```
library(tibble)
library(openxlsx)

data <- tribble(
  ~Week, ~Facility, ~Indicator, ~`Indicator Value`, ~`Yellow Gap`, ~`Green Gap`, ~Score, ~max,
  8, "Mngeta Health Center", "3MMD Coverage", 0.96, -13, 10, 4, 8,
  8, "Mngeta Health Center", "12 Month Retention", 0.96, 35, 50, 2, 4,
  8, "Mngeta Health Center", "Appointment Adherence", 0.97, 11, 24, 0, 8,
  8, "Mngeta Health Center", "EID 12 Months", 1, 0, 0, 8, 8,
  8, "Mngeta Health Center", "Early Retention", 1, 0, 0, 8, 8,
  8, "Mngeta Health Center", "Recent Retention", 1.04, -19, -5, 8, 8,
  8, "Mngeta Health Center", "6MMD Coverage", 0.98, -29, -9, 8, 8,
  8, "Mngeta Health Center", "IPT Coverage", 0.99, -15, -1, 4, 4,
  8, "Mngeta Health Center", "EID 2 Months", 1, 0, 0, 8, 8,
  8, "Mngeta Health Center", "Viral Load Coverage", 0.95, -67, -2, 8, 8
)

# Convert Score column to numeric
data$Score <- as.numeric(data$Score)

wb <- createWorkbook()

# Add a new worksheet
addWorksheet(wb, "Formatted Data")

# Write the data to the worksheet
writeData(wb, "Formatted Data", data)

# Create a style object for green color0
green_style <- createStyle(bgFill = "green")

conditionalFormatting(wb, sheet = "Formatted Data",
                      cols = which(colnames(data) == "Score"), rows = 1:(nrow(data)+1),
                      rule = '"Score"==8 & "max"==8', style = green_style)

saveWorkbook(wb, "formatted_data.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: I have amended as suggested but still not getting the desired conditionally formatted output

Comment: What are you getting and how is it different than what you want?

Comment: I dont get the condtional formatting, but I do get the error "Removed Feature: Conditional formatting from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part"

Comment: I don't actually have excel.  I am using Libre Office Calc. It produces the conditional formatting without errors.   Are you running exactly the code above or is that just for the question and you are actually running other similar code?

Comment: Copied and pasted verbatim

Comment: Sorry, I just started a new R session ran this all again and it worked fine. I have nothing else to offer.

Comment: could you post the  complete code you used?

Comment: Adding full code to answer.

Comment: Still get the errors as shown in the two images above

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: Where do I find the error log?

Comment: The image that you included had a link. \

Comment: I have edited to include contents of error log (image)